# How to speed up pandas read_csv?

Tags: parsing, csv, pandas

I currently parse a text file with the following:

```
f = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
dframe = pd.read_csv(
    fname, sep=' ', header=None,
    names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
    use_unsigned=True, parse_dates=True, index_col=0, date_parser=f)
```

which takes about 5.70 s for a single file.

Can I speedup the datetime parsing?

A line from the file looks like:

```
2015-04-08-11-23-27 12420.8 12430.3 12527.0 12394.2 A
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to speed it up a bit by using `to_datetime` manually instead of using your lambda function:

```
>>> %time df = pd.read_csv(fname, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, 
          names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), use_unsigned=True, parse_dates=True, 
          index_col=0, date_parser=f)
CPU times: user 9.16 s, sys: 39.9 ms, total: 9.2 s
Wall time: 9.2 s
```

vs.

```
>>> %time df2 = pd.read_csv(fname, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), use_unsigned=True, parse_dates=False, index_col=0)
CPU times: user 416 ms, sys: 20 ms, total: 436 ms
Wall time: 435 ms
>>> %time df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
CPU times: user 2.72 s, sys: 4 ms, total: 2.72 s
Wall time: 2.72 s
>>> 
>>> df.equals(df2)
True
>>> (2.72+0.435)/9.2
0.3429347826086957
```

(I'm using `delim_whitespace=True` because that tends to be modestly faster in situations like this.)

Comment: you probably mean

    df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

?